# Why I'm getting duplicate entry exception, when trying to save not new aggregate entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

I have two tables, these are profile_info and user_Info.
Database ER-diagram

[image: ER-Diagram]

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userLogin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userPassword` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userType` enum('user','administrator') DEFAULT NULL,
  `userEmail` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userEmail` (`userEmail`)
);
CREATE TABLE `profile_info` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `userRegistrationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userFirstName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userSurName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountBalance` double DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userUniqueId` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `chk_accountBalance` CHECK ((`accountBalance` >= 0))
);
```

So I have one to one relationship(one profile is related only to one user)

Here are my entities :

User :

```
@Table("user_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Persistable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userLogin")
    private String userLogin;
    @Column("userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    @Column("userType")
    private String userType;
    @Column("userEmail")
    private String userEmail;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

Profile :

```
@Table("profile_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile implements Persistable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userRegistrationDate")
    private LocalDateTime userRegistrationDate;
    @Column("userFirstName")
    private String userFirstName;
    @Column("userSurName")
    private String userSurName;
    @Column("accountBalance")
    private double accountBalance;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "id")
    private User user;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

I use standard repositories as CRUDRepository
UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

ProfileRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile,Integer> {
}
```

In user table I have only two records :

[image]

In profile table I have only one which I'm gonna update

[image]

And I'm trying to insert User entity first, and after that update Profile entity

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    ProfileRepository repository = context.getBean("profileRepository",ProfileRepository.class);
    UserRepository userRepository =context.getBean("userRepository",UserRepository.class);
    User user = new User(null,"Login","newUserP","user","TestEmail");
    userRepository.save(user);
    user.setUserLogin("new bqqvnbvnvbn");
    System.out.println(user.getId());
    Profile profile = new Profile(34, LocalDateTime.now(),"fff","sss",250.0,user);
    repository.save(profile);
}
```

User id is :

[image]

User was succesfully created

[image]

But When I'm trying to update Profile I'm getting error duplicate entry

```
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '77' for key 'user_info.PRIMARY'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1350)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
        ... 38 more
```

But in Spring documentation is said "If the aggregate root is not new, all referenced entities get deleted, the aggregate root gets updated, and all referenced entities get inserted again. Note that whether an instance is new is part of the instance’s state."

So it should delete user from database first and after that update profile and insert deleted user

Also, when I did this I got this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.Insert(entity=User(id=77, userLogin=new bqqvnbvnvbn, userPassword=newUserP, userType=user, userEmail=TestEmail), propertyPath=user, dependingOn=DbAction.UpdateRoot(entity=Profile(id=34, userRegistrationDate=2021-08-15T20:38:16.862, userFirstName=fff, userSurName=sss, accountBalance=250.0, user=User(id=77, userLogin=new bqqvnbvnvbn, userPassword=newUserP, userType=user, userEmail=TestEmail))), qualifiers={})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have repositories for both `User` and `Profile`.
This means both are Aggregate Roots.
Aggregate Roots must only reference each other by id. So `Profile.user` should be of type `Integer`.

Alternatively you might decide that the two entities really form an aggregate. In that case you must:

1. Decide which entity is the Aggregate Root.
2. Remove the repository for the non root entity.
3. You may (should) also remove the id for the non root entity.

See also https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

Note: Implementing `Persistable` as you did is pretty much superfluous because it replicates the default behaviour anyway.

Another note: `@MappedCollection(idColumn = "id")` is ignored for all simple references. It applies only to collections like `List`, `Set` or `Map`.